# API Gateway GET Method Request URL Query String Parameters using AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am configuring API gateway using CDK and I am struggling with URL Query String Parameters in GET Method Request. I could find examples for the integration request but nothing for the Method request.

These are my URL Query String Parameters defined using console, my question is how do I replicate this in TypeScript using CDK?
[image]

I have checked the CDK documentation hoping to find the implementation. I was expecting that it could be under [MethodOptions interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.MethodOptions.html) but there is nothing useful for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code does the job. It is part of the [Method construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.Method.html).

```
 options: {
      requestParameters: {
     'method.request.querystring.profile': true,
     'method.request.querystring.username': true,
     'method.request.querystring.password': true,
     'method.request.querystring.language': true,
     'method.request.querystring.options': false
      }
}
```